# Transpose result table from dplyr or gt

Tags: r, dplyr, gt

I'm using `dplyr` and `gt` to try to produce a summary table. Here is my sample data:

```
structure(list(child.sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("boy", "girl"), class = "factor"), 
    child.age = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 9, 9, 10, 9)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
   child.sex child.age
1       girl         9
2        boy         9
3       girl         9
4        boy         9
5       girl         9
6        boy        10
7       girl         9
8        boy         9
9        boy        10
10       boy         9
```

Here is my code:

```
dt %>%
  group_by(child.sex) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n=n(),mean=mean(child.age),sd=sd(child.age),
                   min=min(child.age), max=max(child.age)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  gt()
```

The result is rather a wide format. I'm wondering how to rearrange the table in a long formate like:

```
       boy     girl
n       6       4
mean   9.333   9.000
sd     0.516   0.000
min     9       9
max     10      9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(child.sex) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n=n(), mean=mean(child.age),sd=sd(child.age),
                   min=min(child.age), max=max(child.age)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-child.sex) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "child.sex", values_from = "value") %>% 
  gt()
```

[image]